# Как правильно по-русски передать "рeople watching"?

Tags: заимствования, варваризмы

> Он высказывал своё мнение, вступая в серьёзные в дискуссии. Он и сам
> предлагал темы для обсуждений. Кроме того, глядя на суетливых
> пожирателей знаний и рассеянных туристов, эта супружеская пара
> умудрялась получать и особое удовольствие, устраивая себе в придачу к
> изысканным интеллектуальным упражнениям весь этот "пиплвотчинг".

А Гугл и отвечает:

> Показаны результаты по запросу пипл вотчинг
>
> Искать вместо этого
> пиплвотчинг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот нашла: 
Люди сидят на многочисленных скамейках в тени раскидистых деревьев и развлекают себя «пиплвотчингом» - т. е. осмотром и комментированием прохожих. http://vertikal-pechatniki.ru/kuda/kuda_kraskra042.htm

“рeople watching” - "люди смотрят", в русском закрепилось слитное написание варваризма «пиплвотчинг» -  созерцание, этакий мониторинг - отслеживание того, что происходит вокруг.

Comment: Людмила, ‘people watching’ означает не "люди смотрят". ‘Watching’ здесь существительное, так же как и ‘people’. Иначе ‘watching of people’ — буквально "наблюдение за людьми".

Comment: Если бы было продолжение или хотя бы словосочетание ‘people watching something’, тогда бы ‘watching’ было причастием и выражение бы означало "люди, наблюдающие за чем-то" или "люди, смотрящие (на) что-то".

Comment: Согласна, я учила немецкий, это мнение сугубо по высказываниям в Интернете. Смотрела переводы - там везде смысл сводится к "люди смотрят".

Comment: @Артем Луговой, все верно: люди смотрят. Не надо переводить дословно. Вообще английскому языку свойственны безпредложные контрукции. Так что там,  где в русском языке может быть предлог, в анлийском может и  не быть. Можно воспринимать эту конструкцию как термин.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь важнее авторский контекст, чем разбор буквального английского смысла авторской словесной находки, а имел он в виду, вероятно, "публичный просмотр", "присутствие множества зевак".

Comment: Все верно, Александр. В Википедии об этом написано.